# Remove object when it can be implied

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

I'd like to know if it is *possible to omit an "object"* from some sentences when the reader can understand the object? if is so it is *necessary to keep propositions of verbs*? consider the following sentences

> Both the reading and the listening discuss the reasons behind ***the mass die-off of sea otters along the Alaskan coast***. The author of the reading believes that environmental pollution mainly **contributes**, and provides three supporting reasons. The lecturer, however, throws doubt on the claims presented in the article, by stating that, in fact, the predation **plays a significant role**.

In fact, "the mass die-off of sea otters along the Alaskan coast" is the object for both "contribue[to]" and "plays a significant role [in]".

*If I can not do that what can I do to avoid repetition?*

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You might say "contributes to the phenomenon" to refer to what was just stated. Then, "plays a significant role" (without the "in"), will be understood to refer to the same subject.